# Need to set Imageview same in all device in android using FancyCoverflow

Tags: android, layout, coverflow

I am working on fancy coverflow. Now as the code shown below

```
 public View getCoverFlowItem(int i, View reuseableView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ImageView imageView = null;

  /*  Display display = viewGroup.getDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int  width = size.x;
    int  height = size.y;*/

    if (reuseableView != null) {
        imageView = (ImageView) reuseableView;
    } else {
        imageView = new ImageView(viewGroup.getContext());
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new FancyCoverFlow.LayoutParams(300,400));


    }

    imageView.setImageResource(this.getItem(i));
    return imageView;
}
```

the layout param which are being passed are static integers.which obviously put Image view at different position in different device. Is there any idea to use like match parent or applying gravity upon it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can set layout params to match parent with

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(
    Gallery.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    Gallery.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

You could also set those to `WRAP_CONTENT` and place correctly sized bitmaps to your `drawable` folders. This will ensure the image has the same size on all screens measured in `dip`.

Comment: As that coverflow utilizes gallery class. It shows class cast exception of something like ViewGroup Layout params can not be cast to Gallery layout params.

Comment: Then replace `ViewGroup` with `Gallery`

Comment: It is not working at all. Simply I want to set height and width of my layout which I am unable to through obvious ways like changing that layoutParams.